# Change value json array localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, session-storage

I would like to change the Used value of for example array 2 from 0 to 1
I am saving said array in localstorage

```
0: {Referencia: "AV02", Descripcion: "TEXT", Precio: "30", Usado: 0}
1: {Referencia: "AV02", Descripcion: "TEXT", Precio: "30", Usado: 0}
2: {Referencia: "AV04", Descripcion: "TEXT", Precio: "0.35", Usado: 0}
3: {Referencia: "AV01", Descripcion: "TEXT", Precio: "45", Usado: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are asking how to change the value of an object property when the object is an element of an array. If so:

```
arrayOfObjects[2].Usado=1;
```

You would have to retrieve the data from localStorage before doing this and put it back to local storage under the same key when you were done (with JSON stringifying and parsing steps as needed, local storage stores strings only, objects and arrays have to be converted to strings before storing).